# Exception java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError after running project

Tags: java, intellij-idea, jar, gradle, build.gradle

I'm trying to run a project in IntelliJ IDEA 14 on OS X Yosemite with .dylib dependencies.
I have next project structure:
[image]

I specified `java.library.path`:[image]

But I'm still getting after running it: `Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: no gsexpat in java.library.path`
Can someone point what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure but why you have \ before "libs" ? Have you tried:
-Djava.library.path=/Users/harry/Documents/Java/FJavaServer/libs ?

Anyway I think the problem is that you need to add the folder with the **gsexpat** library to your library.path as well

Comment: "to add the folder with the gsexpat library to your library.path as well"
Thanks!
That was my fault. I really forgot to add this library to libary.path